# Android studio misconfigured - always displays Lorem Ipsem

Tags: android

I had a simple Android app working but then when I added a new textview control, it began rendering Lorem Ipsum rather than the programmed content. So I build a default app - "Hello Android" - and got the same results: Lorem Ipsem. It seems likely that any project will do the same.

The compile SDK is 34 and the language is Kotlin. I am using Gradle.

I don't see anyplae in MainActivity.kt where it calls for Lorem Ipsem.

```
package com.example.test

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.test.ui.theme.TestTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    TestTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way we can help without source code

Comment: I added the source code to my post. It is the default code supplied by Android Studio. That is why I didn't post it before

Answer (score 0):

OK it turns out that the emulator wasn't running the newly built app, it was running something older that had an error in it. I had to stop the emulator and boot it up again